# How exactly is Newton's Binomial Theorem Proven Using Combinatorial Ideas?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Let $n$ and $k$ be nonnegative integers. The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ is equal to the number of ways to choose $k$ items from a set with $n$ elements. How can this interpretation of $\binom{n}{k}$ be used to understand or prove the binomial theorem
$$
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k} \qquad \text{for all numbers } x, y.
$$

---

**Note**: The original text of this question is shown below. I’m editing the question because it’s fundamental and deserves to be salvaged.

Original text:

Sorry for the childish question. I am in 7th grade and need some help. Thank You!

Comment: One would assume this question is a duplicate, but in my quick search I did not find a duplicate. Has anyone found a duplicate? If this question hasn't been asked before, then it's a great question, although not asked very well due to the inexperienced user. We should either find a duplicate or else improve this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's imagine what happens if we expand
$$
(x+y)^3 = \underbrace{(x+y)}_{\text{factor 1}} \underbrace{(x+y)}_{\text{factor 2}} \underbrace{(x+y)}_{\text{factor 3}} 
$$
without collecting like terms. The result is
\begin{align}
(x + y)^3 &= x\cdot x \cdot x \\
& + x \cdot x \cdot y + x \cdot y \cdot x + y \cdot x \cdot x \\
&+ x \cdot y \cdot y + y \cdot x \cdot y + y \cdot y \cdot x \\
&+ y \cdot y \cdot y.
\end{align}
Each term in the sum contains a contribution from factor 1, a contribution from factor 2, and a contribution from factor 3. Each factor contributes either an $x$ or a $y$.

Now how many terms in this sum are equal to $x y^2$? Well, how many ways are there to choose two of the factors to contribute a $y$? The answer is $\binom{3}{2}$.

Likewise, the sum contains $\binom{3}{0}$ terms that are equal to $x^3$, $\binom{3}{1}$ terms that are equal to $x^2 y$, and $\binom{3}{3}$ terms that are equal to $y^3$.

That explains why
$$
(x + y)^3 = \binom{3}{0} x^3 + \binom{3}{1}x^2 y + \binom{3}{2} x y^2 + \binom{3}{3} y^3.
$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

The Binomial Theorem says:
$$
(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}  a^{n-k}b^k,
$$
where the left hand side is
$$
\underbrace{(a+b)\cdot(a+b)\cdot(a+b)\cdot\ldots\cdot(a+b)}_{n \ times}.
$$
If you would expand this product you would pick one element from each bracket. This last sentence could already ring some bells since combinatorics usually deals with questions *"In now many different ways can I pick..."*.

For a more detailed explanation you could look at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Hope this helped a bit and you are always welcome to add further questions and ideas as a comment on my answer